# How do I set up commons-logging to use logback?

Tags: java, logging, logback, apache-commons-logging

We use slf4j + logback, and happened to have some third-party libraries which use commons-logging. How do I set it up to use logback?

Comment: have you tried replacing commons-logging.jar with jcl-over-slf4j.jar?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The answer is to not use commons-logging.jar, since SLF4J was designed to do what commons-logging does but better. As @MahdeTo refers to, you need to use jcl-over-slf4j.jar.

Check out the documentation from the slf4j website [on migrating from commons-logging](http://slf4j.org/legacy.html#jcl-over-slf4j).

Comment: Didn't you read the question? They are using third party libraries which use commons logging.

Comment: Indeed. But you can save the pedantic and strictest literal reading to see that I meant that the OP shouldn't use the commons-logging.jar. The OP got that, so why the need to add a non-constructive comment?

Comment: Please also check the FAQ of SLF4J, which show how commons-logging can be excluded from the maven dependencies: http://slf4j.org/faq.html#excludingJCL

Comment: LOL at the person that down-voted this answer, and without explaining why. Great job at not understanding the subject of the question, and the platform on which it was asked, all at the same time.

Comment: Suggested edit: instead of "The answer is to not use commons-logging" make it "The answer is to not use commons-logging.jar".

Comment: I think this is clear. "don't use commons-logging" - but use another library that implements the api. ps. let's be civil, people!

Comment: So I don't get a "LOL at the person that down-voted this answer, and without explaining why", see the upvoted comments for why.

Answer (score 20):

I come across this question too, and found out `jcl-over-slf4j.jar` indeed can solve the problem, I couldn't understand that why `commons-logging` couldn't use `logback` automatically, since `commons-logging` is log interface and `logback` is implementation, they should integrate automatically, until I found [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/guide.html):

> The Apache Commons Logging (JCL) provides a Log interface that is
>   intended to be both light-weight and an independent abstraction of
>   other logging toolkits. It provides the middleware/tooling developer
>   with a simple logging abstraction, that allows the user (application
>   developer) to plug in a specific logging implementation.
>
> JCL provides thin-wrapper Log implementations for other logging tools,
>   including Log4J, Avalon LogKit (the Avalon Framework's logging
>   infrastructure), JDK 1.4, and an implementation of JDK 1.4 logging
>   APIs (JSR-47) for pre-1.4 systems. The interface maps closely to Log4J
>   and LogKit.

Obviously not all the log interface can integrate nicely with log implementation which mean, if you really want to use `logback`, `jcl-over-slf4j.jar` is your only solution now because `JCL` only support `Log4J, Logkit, JDK 1.4`.

Answer (score 5):

Just add `jcl-over-slf4j` to the dependencies of your project (check current version at https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.slf4j%20AND%20a:jcl-over-slf4j&core=gav)

Answer (score 2):

for those all who wants to keep the final package size smaller; checkout 
`mvn dependency:tree` result of your project and if any dependency to `commons-logging` exists, exclude them as well. Since the `jcl-over-slf4j.jar` contains both Log and LogFactory classes with exact same package structure, these commons-logging jars will be extra on your final package.

Comment: this answer is not only for "those all who wants to keep the final package size smaller", but it is a must-do for everyone who wants to use jcl-over-slf4j